# problem with VSCode IDE for writing react code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I just start to write some codes in react in VScode but after creating a default project by "[create-react-project](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/README.md#getting-started)" based on the [Mosh tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0). I have some warning by VS code when I open APP.JS as shown below.
would you mind tell me why I am receiving these warning? I am confused about what is right and what is wrong in my code.
[image]

Comment: It's a linting setting: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/jsx-quotes seems like your linting rules are enforcing the use of single quotes and giving errors for double quotes.

Comment: @Jayce444: Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [standard] Unexpected usage of doublequote. (jsx-quotes)

...is an ESLint rule, details of which, can be found [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/jsx-quotes) - You've got a few choices:

1. Disable ESLint (probably via some VS Code extension) or a setting thereof
2. Use inline disabling for specific rules (generally frowned upon)
3. Continue to use ESLint for coding standards and use only single quotes.